# std::vector<char> and getting the next line to a delimiting character

Tags: c++, vector

I was curious if there is an efficient way to obtain a string of chars from a char vector ending with a delimiting char such as /n.

Comment: Yes there's but what have you try ?

Answer (score 2):

There must be a copy, because an `std::vector<char>` and a `std::string` cannot share memory.  Given that, if you want to stop at the first `'\n'`:

```
std::string s( v.begin(), std::find( v.begin(), v.end(), '\n' ) );
```

should do the trick.  (The resulting string will *not* contain the `'\n'`.)

More likely, you'll want to save the results of `std::find` in an intermediate variable, so that you can continue parsing the rest of the vector later.